# CSS - position:absolute behaving strangely and moving elements

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a [WooCommerce store](http://hibernian.ruairimcnicholas.com/shop/) and am making changes to the page that displays all products. It's a poor theme - the "Read More" buttons for each product aren't aligned, they're moved by the title if it's more than one line:

[image]

My solution:

- Set the min and max width of the container each product is in to the same value to make them all equal height
- Put the following CSS on each button:

  bottom: 0;

  position: absolute;

This worked, except for one issue:
Where a products title **only takes up one line**, the Read More button breaks out of the container:

[image]

I'm wondering why this happens at all, and then, why this only happens when the title is of one line in length?

My fix is to also add "float: left" to each button, but this moves it a bit too far let and I have to correct this with "margin-left".

Suggestions for a better way to do this, as well as why the issue occurs, would be fantastic!

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use flex ([see this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) for browser support), I would highly recommend that over `position:absolute` for its simplicity and especially for the responsive version of the site.

Here is the CSS3 you could use (after removing your absolute):

```
.woocommerce ul.products li {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

/**
 * flex-grow: 1; will make the header 'grow' as large as
 * possible to fit the available space and 'push' the link
 * down to the bottom.
 */
.woocommerce ul.products li header {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.woocommerce ul.products li > a {
    text-align: center;
}
```

It will especially avoid headaches when trying to avoid overlap, etc.

Comment: A big plus on the responsiveness.

Answer (score 0):

Believe I could follow you're idea on the min-height and position absolute...

```
// Only problem is, you also need a media query now :s
.bpgPhoto {
    ...
    min-height: 200px; // so scratch that
    padding: 50%; // this is the responsive embed technique
}

.boldPhotoBox {
    ...
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.boldPhotoBox .bpbItem,
.boldPhotoBox .bpbItem .btImage {
    ...
    height: 100%;
}

// since the images differ in height, 
// and you want to keep their aspect ratio, 
// I'd suggest to add the border on the image class, rather than the `img` tag itself.
.boldPhotoBox .bpbItem .btImage {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.07);
}

.btLightSkin.woocommerce-page .product img {
    border: none;
}
```

More info on the [responsive embed technique](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/responsive-helpers/) by Bootstrap, but, I've used it many years before... pfuh ^^